# output of multilevel inheritance program code

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

```
 #include<iostream>
 using namespace std;

 class A {
      int i;
public: 
    // A() {cout<<"in A's def const\n";};
     A(int k) {cout<<"In A const\n";  i = k; }
    };

class B :  public A {
public:
    //B(){cout<<"in B's def const\n";};
    B(int i) : A(i) {cout<<"in B const\n";}
    };

  class C :   public B {
  public:
    C() {cout<<"in C def cstr\n";}
    C(int i) : B(i) {cout<<"in C const\n";}
    };

 int main()
 {
    C obj=new C(2);
    return 0;
   }
```

when i am running this code it shows 
        In constructor 'C::C()':
          88c8237e3ffce7819f082b210069fd59.cpp:19:13: error: no matching function for          call to 'B::B()'

why this happens as i am only caling parameterized constructors explicitly everywhere.??please help
         C() {cout<<"in C def cstr\n";}

Comment: _" i am only caling parameterized constructors explicitly everywhere"_ - Look again, you're not.

Comment: If you do not explicitly specify any base class constructor, then the default constructor is called. Since your class B has no base class constructor so you have an error.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot declare

```
C() {cout<<"in C def cstr\n";}
```

Because neither of the base classes `A` nor `B` have default (non-parameterized) constructors. If you uncommented those out [your code would compile](http://cpp.sh/3gc6k) (except for the comment below).

Side comment, this is not correct

```
C obj=new C(2);
```

You could use any of the following

```
C obj(2);
C obj{2};
C obj = C(2);
```

But with `new` you'd have to assign to a pointer (which I wouldn't recommend unless you need heap allocated objects for some reason, in which case prefer smart pointers).

```
C* obj = new C(2);
delete obj; // remember to delete it when you're done
```